# Invariance of form under flow

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Take a two-dimensional symplectic submanifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now, I want to show that the symplectic form $\omega$ is invariant under the Hamiltonian flow $\phi^{t}: M \rightarrow M.$

Is it now sufficient to show that for any two-dimensional submanifold $N$ of $M$ we have $\int_{N} \omega = \int_{\phi^{t}(N)} \omega$ for any $t$ and $N$? So does this imply that $(\phi^t)^* \omega = \omega$? Since $ \int_{\phi^{t}(N)} \omega = \int_N (\phi^t)^* \omega$ this reduces to the question whether $\int_{N} \omega = \int_N (\phi^t)^* \omega$ implies  $(\phi^t)^* \omega = \omega$ ?

Edit: Since I received answers trying to propose different ways of solving this problem, I should mention that I want to prove it exactly the way I proposed.

Comment: I don't really understand why you're trying to integrate. This is surely proved somewhere in McDuff-Salamon; all you have to do is notice that the derivative $(\phi^t)^*\omega$ with respect to $t$ is the definition of the Lie derivative of $\omega$ with respect to $X_H$. Some manipulation shows that this is zero.

Comment: @MikeMiller yes, but I want to prove it with a direct calculation and all that is missing is this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_t$ denote the time dependent vector field generating $\phi_t$, and let $H_t$ be a smooth family of corresponding Hamiltonian functions. Then$$\mathcal{L}_{X_t}\omega=di_{X_t}\omega+i_{X_t}d\omega=ddH_t=0,$$and hence $\omega$ is preserved by $\phi_t$. Note that this holds for any Hamiltonian flow in any symplectic manifold, not only surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: that was not my question, sorry

Comment: I mean here all the work is in the formula you use there.

Comment: @user167575 Hey, this is called Cartan's formula, and you should get to know it. This is the standard way to prove that the symplectic structure is preserved under Hamiltonian flow, in any symplectic manifold.